# Deleting item in child from parent component

Tags: vue.js

I'm using scoped slots to delete item in a child component. I'm receiving the id from the child component and deleting them on the parent. The delete is successful but I'm a bit confused on how to remove the item on the child component once deleted.

**Parent**

```
<template>
    <Commitment :commitments="commitments">
        <template #default="{commitmentID}">
            <button @click="deleteCommitment(commitmentID)">
                <i class="lni lni-trash text-2xl mt-5"></i>
            </button>
        </template>
    </Commitment>
</template>

<script>
import Commitment from "@/Pages/Commitment/Card";

export default {
    props: {
        commitments: {}
    },
    methods: {
        deleteCommitment(id) {
            axios.delete("/commitment/" + id).then(res => {
                console.log('deleted')
            });
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
    <ul class="text-lg mt-4">
        <li class="mb-1" v-for="commitment in commitments" :key="commitment.id">
            <div class="flex justify-between">
                <div>
                    <i class="lni lni-pointer-right"></i>&nbsp;
                    {{ commitment.details }}
                </div>
                <div>USD{{ commitment.amount }}</div>
                <slot :commitmentID="commitment.id"></slot>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        commitments: {}
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The item has to be removed from `commitments` as well.  And since `commitments` is a prop in the parent as well, it has to be deleted in the parent's parent to avoid mutating the prop.  (Vuex would make this simpler.)

Comment: I know vuex would be simpler, but curious if there was a way

Comment: Yep, see my comment:  you have to remove the item from the parent's parent, or wherever the `commitments` data is first set (to avoid mutating a prop).  So that means emitting an event to it and then calling a delete method there